# How to update object in list

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist, angular6

I have strange trouble with a simple case :

I get calendar with Events (Interventions object).

When I click on event, it opens modal.

To get modal info before opening, I use "findByTicket" method located in my "CalendarServices" service:

```
 findByTicket(list: Intervention[], idSearch: number) {
    return (list.find((x) => x.ticketDTO.idaiticket === idSearch));
}
```

This is the TS file that call this method :

```
openEventModal (event, action) {
    console.log('Start openEventModal');
    let intervention = this.calendarServices.findByTicket(this.confirmList, event.event.id);
    if (typeof intervention === 'undefined') {
        intervention = this.calendarServices.findByTicket(this.interventionInitList, event.event.id);
        if (typeof intervention === 'undefined') {
            console.log('nouveau ticket => ' + typeof intervention);
            intervention = {} as Intervention;
            // blabla
        } else {
            console.log('this.interventionInitList avant open: ');
            console.log(this.interventionInitList);
            console.log('intervention existante => ' + typeof intervention);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('ticket ou intervention réédité ' + typeof intervention );
    }
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalInterventionComponent, {
        height: '50%',
        width: '50%',
        maxWidth: '100vw',
        maxHeight: '100vh',
        autoFocus: false,
        data: {
            myJarviaServices: this.myJarviaServices,
            contactsList: this.contactsList,
            prestatairesList: this.prestatairesList,
            typesList: this.typesList,
            intervention: intervention,
            action: action
        }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result !== null) {
            console.log('this.interventionInitList en sortie de modal: ');
            console.log(this.interventionInitList);
            if (action === 1) { 
                // case 1
            } else {  
                 // case 2
            }
        } else {
            if (action === 1) {
               // case 3
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In this case : Intervention object is retrieved, by using "findByTicket" function, in "interventionInitList" list, that contains original informations of each intervention (there are 2 interventions).

The problem happens when I close modal after updating info :
"interventionInitList" item is also updated with the value I choose in modal!!
Why ???

Here is log (console.log instructions) before opening with original info:
Intervention object is sent to modal

[image]

And this is log after updating Intervention objet info in modal:

[image]

the item is also updating. But I never update interventionInitList in my code...

Why does-it keep this "link" and how can I solve it ?
I just want to retrieve original info in this list,but not updating it

Comment: That "link" is called a reference. You are referencing the same object. You could do something like this: `return Object.assign({}, (list.find((x) => x.ticketDTO.idaiticket === idSearch)));` to make a copy of the object.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! But I get another problem : In some case, the list must be updated. So I get the object with your solution and I use "indexOf()" method to get the index but now it returns -1 ...I find this link to test : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-item-edit-jk7b9k

Comment: Well yes, it's the same problem again. Now you can't find it because it DOESN'T reference the same object. You can find it by ID like: `.find(object => object.id === toFind.id)`

Comment: Or `indexOf` by id, of course

Comment: OK. So if I use reference, I don't need to get index in order to update list (ex: myList[index] = updated reference.... ) I just update the reference, retrieved by find() method and the list will be automatically updated

Comment: Yes. That's the same object you are altering, after all.